# regexreplace and duplicate characters - google spreadsheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to get rid of duplicates when I make a replacement.

```
=regexreplace("extra---dashes--here","-","?")
```

Results in:

> extra???dashes??here

Is there a way to write that in order to not return multiple "?" in the result?

Actually, let me clarify that a bit.
I'm using regex because I actually have a number of different characters that I'm replacing (not just a dash, as in this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a quantifier in the regex pattern:

```
regexreplace('extra---dashes--here','-+','?')
```

That tells it to replace one or more consecutive hyphens with a single question mark.